# convert iterator to lambda

Tags: java, lambda, iterable

My linter advises me to refactor this using lambda expressions, but I can't figure out how to do it for this piece of code

```
        return new Iterable<Message>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Message> iterator() {
                return new UnprocessedIterator(message);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Hint: a decent IDE, like IntelliJ not only tells you about "this could be a lambda", but also does the conversion for you, most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `return () -> new UnprocessedIterator(message);` should work.